# Проблемы при попытке преобразовать картинку в base64, Python3, Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

Есть такая функция в python3:

```
def image_to_base64(image_file, format_img='jpg'):
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + str(encoded_string)
```

Она принимает 2 аргумента: ImageField object из django и формат изображения, функция работает, но появляется такая проблема - строка возвращается в таком формате:
data:image/jpeg;base64,b'*сама строка*'.
Вопрос, что значит выражение b' ', откуда оно берётся и как это убрать, костылять вырезая из полученной строки b' ' как-то не очень хочется, может кто-то знает более правильный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) получает и возвращает набор байт (байтовую строку). Если байтовую строку преобразовать в строку с помощью `str`, то в начало добавится `b` и все содержимое будет обернуто в кавычки (то же самое произойдет если вы попытаетесь вывести эту строку, например, через `print`). Вам нужно эту байтовую строку декодировать в обычную строку с помощью метода `decode` (в данном случае будет применена кодировка по-умолчанию, насколько я помню это `'latin'`):

```
return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + encoded_string.decode()
```